# How do I implement a node js query that is supposed to display data for specific model from two different tables? I am using the loopback framework

Tags: node.js, loopback

I have a table that holds Assessment Data with the following headings.
Stud_id | SessionId | CourseId | ProgId | .....

And a student Data that holds Student data with the following headings.
id | IndexNo | S_name | f_name | ProgramId.

The relationship between these two fields is that Student has many assessment and assessment belongs to student.
What I want to do is to list all students with these fields(Index No, S_name, f_name, Course) who registered for a course and pass it as a json endpoint to a client who makes a request with courseId, SessionId. deptId.

Comment: What is the database you're using?If it is mongoose, then check the `Populate()` method

Comment: Are you using mongoose or sql?

Comment: I am using cockroach db